# Appointment Scheduling

Tags: 7, datetime

I am looking to create an apointment scheduling system on drupal 7.x, however all of the modules and instructions that I can find are for 6.x. The system is fairly simple, and only needs to be able to have users schedule appointments for certain blocks of time.

How would I go about doing this in 7.x? Are there any modules that I can use, or is there some way to "hack" this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the [signup](http://drupal.org/project/signup) module for this - we actually used it for tax appointments this year. Yes, it's 7 version is in development but I don't see it being very much different from the 6.x version.

It enables you to attach "slots" to nodes and have people sign up for them. They can be timed or untimed. As the 7.x version is a straight port from the 6.x version, all the tutorials should be the same.

Comment: Thank you, I have been able to get this (somewhat) working. I may try to develop my own module for this in the upcoming months, if I have time.

Comment: Hi,I am also interested in this module.Did you create one?

Comment: Im interested in this, i want people to be abe to book my time and see a calendar of when im free or busy

Comment: You could also use MERCI if you want something quite more complex.

Comment: I'm not seeing how you can create "slots" with the signup module or any options for timed/untimed.  Any clues or tutorial links for that?

Comment: @Reid Did you create a module?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you are looking for: module [Click to Schedule](https://www.drupal.org/project/click_to_schedule).

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... a new, proven way to convert website visitors into booked appointments or meetings for you and your team using [online appointment scheduling](http://www.timetrade.com/).
>
> It enhances your Drupal website by providing your visitors with a hassle-free way to schedule time with people in your organization simply by clicking a button. No back-and-forth emails or phone calls and no manual follow-up required.
>
> Meetings are automatically confirmed, added to your Outlook, Google Calendar, or iCal and confirmation emails are sent to both parties. You never have to say, “Let me check my schedule” again. You’ll spend less time with the hassle of booking appointments and more time focusing on your business.
>
> When you install the Click-to-Schedule module, you automatically get these features right out of the box:
>
> - A free TimeTrade account
> - Sync capabilities for Outlook, Google calendar or iCal for Mac
> - A click-to-schedule button in the size and color that you choose
> - Appointments and meetings from your website on the calendars of up to 3 of your team members
> - Full control over the times web visitors have to choose from. Just because a time is free on your calendar doesn’t mean it’s available to the public if you don’t want it to be.

Comment: that module is a bit dated from jan-2013. has anyone else tried it?